# fields in mapping are not included in the search results returned by ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I put a mapping into ES as followed:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/developer/document/_mapping -d '
{
      "document" : {
        "properties" : {
          "content" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
            "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
            "copy_to":"single_word_content"
          },
          "ID" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "title" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
            "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
            "copy_to":"single_word_content"
          },
          "single_word_content":{
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer":"standard",
           }
        }
    }
}'
```

Then I insert a document **without** single_word_content field into ES.
When I search from ES, no single_word_content field returned in the search results & highlight not working on single_word_content field either

Answer (score 0):

There is an important note ES documentation about this.

> The original _source field will not be modified to show the copied values.

You can check the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/copy-to.html). This note is valid for 5.0. So, you can specifically indicate your copy fields to get back in your search result.